# Variable Syntax Inside Formula VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

This one has me stumped. Syntax inside the sum formula is throwing an object error. According to what I read, it should work, but I'm missing something. Anyone know what's wrong? Thanks for your help!

```
Range("E" & (i + 2) & ":AL" & (i + 2)).Formula = "=sum(E49:E " & (i + 3) & ")"
```

Comment: Get rid of the space after the `E`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
 Range("E" & (i + 2) & ":AL" & (i + 2)).Formula = "=sum(E49:E" & (i + 3) & ")"
```